# See whether it is possible to perform an operation like i am doing with functions and structures

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct user
{
  string name;
  int age;
  string address;
};

user fun(user u);

void show(user u); //is it possible to perform this 

int main()
{
  user u;
  fun(u);
  show(u);
}

user fun(user u)
{
  char chr;
  cout << "Enter name ";
  cin >> u.name;
  cout << "Enter age ";
  cin >> u.age;
  cout << "Enter address ";
  cin >> u.address; // if I call the show function in here I can see the details I entered  

  {
    // cout<<"Do you want to see what you entered "
    // cin >> chr;
    // if(chr == 'y')
    // {
    //   show(u); // previously "fune(u);" [sic]
    // }
    // else
    // {
    //   cout << endl << "not possible";
    // }
    // return u;
  }
}

void show(user u)
{
  // continuing from line 25:: if i want to print the values like this than it is not performing operations
  cout << endl << u.name;
  cout << endl << u.age;
  cout << endl << u.address;
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?
It's unreadable almost. Please format your question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue in not in `show` (even if you can pass argument by const reference instead of by value), but in `fun` which has several flows.

Should be:

```
void fill_user(user& u) // pass by reference
{
  char chr;
  cout << "Enter name ";
  cin >> u.name;
  cout << "Enter age ";
  cin >> u.age;
  cout << "Enter address ";
  cin >> u.address;
}
```

with usage

```
int main()
{
  user u;
  fill_user(u);
  show(u);
}
```

or even better

```
user input_user()
{
  user u;
  char chr;
  cout << "Enter name ";
  cin >> u.name;
  cout << "Enter age ";
  cin >> u.age;
  cout << "Enter address ";
  cin >> u.address;
  return u;
}
```

with usage

```
int main()
{
  /*const*/ user u = input_user();
  show(u);
}
```

Comment: jarod 42 passing by ref ws the cause to solved the prob thnks buddy